# RadioButton text which is in groupView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have few radio buttons in groupView and every radiobutton has its own text. If this text has more than one line then radio button for this text is center aligned with text but i'd like to align radiobutton to the top of its text.

**My Aim :-**

I have:

```
   | text line 1

RB | text line 2

   | text line 3
```

I want:

```
     RB    
 | text line 1

 | text line 2

 | text line 3
```

For setting text i use rb.setText( text );

Comment: Ok... I don't get what is going on...

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting your requirement as an answer.

Comment: I will suggest you to delete your answer, as I have updated your question. It will help in avoiding confusion to others, and you form down voting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a way. I wonder if it is possible to do this with radiobutton text attribute.

Comment: If u want to do this using attributes instead of building linearlayout with textview and radiobutton then set gravity TOP for radiobutton.